# Where do I place Scala jar libs in Windows?

Tags: jar, scalac

I have installed scala-async.jar for Eclipse (it is easy to edit the .classpath file) but **I also want to compile/run it with command line scala**. `Scalac` says `object async is not a member of package scala`. **Where do I place the jar**?

Answer (score 0):

Placing maven released-jar into `C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\lib` did the trick. I have figured out the folder location with [Process Monitor](https://www.google.ee/search?q=Process%20Monitor).